# GStreamer.Framework and XCode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gstreamer

I want use GStreamer with iOS but when I add framework to my project, then Xcode throw 31 errors about undefined symbols for `armv7`

My framework pack is from [gstreamer.freedesktop.org](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/ios/1.2.2/)

1.After download and install (~/Library/Developer/GStreamer) I put GStreamer.Framework in Project folder.

2.Then I edit searching path for Frameworks `$(PROJECT_DIR)` and Headers `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Headers`

3.Add Gstreamer.framework in Link Binary With Libraries and atm Xcode autocomplete  but throw 30-31 errors abour undeclared symbols for armv7

[image: errors]

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that used binary framework is compiled for armv7?

Comment: Not for 100% and Xcode say it isn't so I search for some info and found this http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/GStreamer-SDK-Preview-Release-for-iOS-td4659652.html I will post info about it.

Comment: Mmm... they suggest to use XCode 4.6 but it also an old post, as the package as been released at the end of previous year. So it should works also on XCode 5. Have you tried to compile for real device or for simulator only? ( real device = ARM, simulator = Intel )

Comment: Ehh... now I have problem with redefinition iconv_hooks and iconv_fallbacks but according to this discution http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Compiling-error-with-quot-GStreamer-SDK-2013-6-Congo-for-iOS-quot-td4662759.html they recomend version with I came here at start. Wrong circle

Comment: which versions have you tried?

Comment: @LucaIaco 1.2.2 and now 1.2.0. What's intresting tutorials from gstreamer.com and lib from ther is working but version of gstreamer is super outdated.